# website server starting to get traffic

Tags: centos, mysql, php

I have a website that's a lot like Bitly, a short url site and it has started to gain a lot of traction lately. The website is about 100MB and the mysql database around 6GB. I run the server on a VPS running CentOS that's on a Dual Intel Xeon CPUs with 32 cores and i have 6GB och ram allocated to it currently with a load of 2.5~ish all the time. The website itself get's about (Acording to awstats) 2650 daily visits, 12K pages and 65K hits. The traffic i genuine, direct ,organic and mostly from social media.

free -m on the server shows this.

> total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
>
> 5120     2710      662     193   1747    2324

Now. As i said it's a short url site and the page has users statistics for each url and those querys has started to take a long time to execute lately. The page itself it fine. i ran a speedtest using Gmetrix and it loads in 3.2seconds under the current load. Mysql is thing slowing down the more traffic increase. I am no sysadmin and i do not know if i am "good" with the current setup or what i should / could do to improve performance hope that anyone have any tips / recommendations.

Comment: If you are delivering TEXTs or BLOBs, are you holding them in a table column?  (This may be less efficient than having the browser asking you web page for them, a la `<img...>`.  Do you have the appropriate indexes?  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the slowest query.  High CPU (which is the only issue you mention) is usually an indexing or query-design issue.

Comment: Sorry, "2650 daily visits," is NOT "a lot of traction". "said it's a short url site and the page has users statistics for each url and those querys has started to take a long time to execute lately." - which is why you do normally NOT DO THEM ON THE FLY. THe more data, the more time. This is not a systadmin issue, this is utterly crap programming. ad joc queries take longer the more data there is, tell the programmer to do his job properly.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.